# Interrogate state of TinyMCE so as to re-initialise in the same state

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE 5. I have an image_list defined, which I need to change dynamically as images are manipulated elsewhere in the page.
I do this by calling tinymce.remove() followed by tinyme.init(), initialising with a new config object which has the updated image_list.

However if the user has changed the state, e.g. by clicking 'paste as text', when the editor re-initialises those changes will be lost.

Can I interrogate the editor state, so I can re-initialise it to the same state it was in when it closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now found a way of doing this that is documented: [TinyMCE 5 Docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/)
The ExecCommand event is fired when (almost) any toolbar button is clicked, providing a way to keep track of the Editor state by adding to the editor config object something like:

```
setup: function(editor) {
   editor.on('ExecCommand', function(e) {
     alert('command was '+e.command+', value was '+e.value);
   }
 )}
```

In the case of the 'Paste as text' button, the command value is 'mceTogglePlainTextPaste'.
Then continue as above in Michael Fromin's answer

Answer (score 1):

Each time you toggle Paste As Text the editor does fire an event (`PastePlainTextToggle`) so you could choose to listen to that event and keep track of if it is toggled on or off.

You could then (upon reinitialization of the editor) call `editor.execCommand('mceTogglePlainTextPaste')` to enable it if that was the last state set during the prior editing session.

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle showing how you might be able to track this setting:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/DRgaab

Comment: Thanks, this works. However I can't find this event documented in the TinyMCE documentation. And therefore, since my alternative below is slightly less code, I'm going to stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Found one way to do this:

`tinymce.editors.<your text area name>.plugins.paste.clipboard.pasteFormat.get()`

will return 'text' or 'html' according to the current 'paste as text' setting.

Of course this is undocumented, so not ideal.